# Why .accdb is missing from dropdown list of SQL server data source?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I try to convert an access database(accdb) into Sql Server but when I want to select .accdb from data source drop down list is missing, only .mdb type is possible.[image]

Comment: Add the Access drivers to your SQL server: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: still do not have accdb in the list

Comment: That's strange. It should be called something like "Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider." Restart SSMS?